# Laravel multi result set query builder

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, sqlsrv

I have a `MSSQL` stored procedure :

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT [ID],
           [Type],
           [message]
    FROM [ir.pay].[dbo].[notifications]
    WHERE ReciverID = @userID;
    SELECT ID AS id,
           Website AS website,
           Status AS status
    FROM dbo.Customers
    WHERE UserID = @userID;
END;
```

And i am executing this with my `laravel` app :

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select('EXEC StoredProcedureName  @userID=1');
```

It just returns me the first `SELECT` query result.

How can i get both result sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by writing bellow function :

```
function get_multi_result_set($conn, $statement)
{
    $results = [];
    $pdo = DB::connection($conn)->getPdo();
    $result = $pdo->prepare($statement);
    $result->execute();
    do {
        $resultSet = [];
        foreach ($result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $res) {
            array_push($resultSet, $res);
        }
        array_push($results, $resultSet);
    } while ($result->nextRowset());

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that your stored procedure returns more than one result set, so you have to move to the next result set. I'm not familiar with Laravel, but I think that you use SQLSRV driver for PHP. So, in this case I use `sqlsrv_next_result()` or `PDOStatement::nextRowset()`. Find appropriate method in Laravel and check.

Comment: Thanks, it helped

Answer (score 0):

You need `union`:

```
SELECT [ID], [Type], [message]
FROM [ir.pay].[dbo].[notifications]
WHERE ReciverID = @userID 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Website, Status
FROM dbo.Customers
WHERE UserID = @userID;
```

Comment: Is there any way to get this with array? without union

Comment: @SaeedVaziry have you got any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `DB::statement();`

For creatigng a store procedure you can create like this.
E.g

```
DB::statement('
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT [ID],
           [Type],
           [message]
    FROM [ir.pay].[dbo].[notifications]
    WHERE ReciverID = @userID;
    SELECT ID AS id,
           Website AS website,
           Status AS status
    FROM dbo.Customers
    WHERE UserID = @userID;
END;

');
```

And for running Store Procedures you can

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->statement('EXEC StoredProcedureName  @userID=1');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have access to queries. i have to execute stored procedure

Comment: This returns true false

Comment: try DB::raw() instead of statement